# Selecting rows which have a similar value for a particular column which occurs n times each month

Tags: mysql, date, select, conditional-statements

I have a database with multiple columns from which I have created this view where I have multiple rows similar to the ones shown below. The data is available for each day of the month from 2009 to 2010 and for all the month for the 5 names given. I have to get the 'Name' for which the occurrence of category 'Super' is more than 5 times each month and list them out separately for each month. The view contains data for all months together.

```
Name  Dates      Category
--------------------------------
PAT  2009-01-01 Super
YAT  2009-01-01 No 
ROT  2009-01-01 No 
SUP  2009-01-01 Super 
ANT  2009-01-01 Super
```

I tried getting a count of the Name in MySQL using

```
SELECT `NAME`,`DATES` 
FROM (
        SELECT `NAME`, `CATEGORY`,MONTH(`DATES`)
        FROM VIEW
        GROUP BY `NAME`, `CATEGORY`,MONTH(`DATES`)
        HAVING COUNT(`CATEGORY`)>5 
    ) a
GROUP BY `NAME`
HAVING count(`CATEGORY`)>5;
```

But it does not return any rows.

Comment: What happens if you run the query while leaving off `HAVING COUNT(CATEGORY)>5` ? Do you get anything?

Comment: @OllieJones It displays a mysql syntax error message when I do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to group your rows into months. The best way to do this is to start with an expression that will take any date and convert it to the first day of the month in which it occurs. That expression is.

```
 DATE(DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%Y-%m-01'))
```

Next, you use this expression in a query with a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT NAME, CATEGORY, 
       DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01')) DATES
  FROM VIEW
 GROUP BY NAME, CATEGORY, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01'))
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

This will yield all the name / category / month combinations occurring more than five times.

I think that's what you want.  But maybe you want *all* the monthly items listed in any month where the Super category appears more than five times for some name.  To do that first we write a subquery to get a list of those dates:

```
            SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01')) DATES
              FROM VIEW
             WHERE CATEGORY = 'Super'
             GROUP BY NAME, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01'))
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
```

Then we write a main query to get all the data

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       NAME, CATEGORY, 
       DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01')) DATES
  FROM VIEW
 WHERE DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01')) IN
        (
            SELECT DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01')) DATES
              FROM VIEW
             WHERE CATEGORY = 'Super'
             GROUP BY NAME, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(DATES, '%Y-%m-01'))
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
        )
```

The trick to getting this sort of thing to work is choosing the right date-arithmetic expression to use in your `GROUP BY` clause. The functions like `DAY()`, `MONTH()`, and `YEAR()` are surprisingly difficult to use correctly, so  I think you may find `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%Y-%m-01'))` more reliable.